# Unix or Python3. Retrieve all columns that start with "N_"

Tags: python-3.x, unix

I have a 6GB file with ~1000 rows and ~4,000,000 columns. This is the format:

```
ID SEX PV APV N_rs1982983 E_rs1982983 N_rs95645 E_rs95645
1 0 45.2 11.1 0 2 0 1
2 1 34.4 10.8 1 1 1 1
```

Using unix or Python3, I would like to retrieve all columns that begin with the string "N_". Columns 3-4 have floats and the rest have integers.

Comment: Are these columns tab separated or space?

Comment: Hi @Shawn, space

Comment: Hi @Shawn, but I can split this huge file into 22, keeping the first 4 columns in each (ID SEX PV APV) which are the same for each individual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 million columns seems insane, but assuming you have a decent amount of memory available, this `perl` one-liner should do the trick (I don't know python, sorry):

```sh
$ perl -lane 'if ($. == 1) {
                $, = " ";
                for (0..$#F) {
                  push @cols, $_ if $F[$_] =~ /^N_/
                }
              }
              print @F[@cols]' input.txt
N_rs1982983 N_rs95645
0 0
1 1
```

Basically, it splits each line into columns on whitespace like `awk` thanks to `-a` into an array `@F`. On the first line it builds a list of the indexes of all columns starting with `N_`, and prints out only those columns for all lines.